# How are pods in kube-system namespace managed?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to understand how kubernetes works, so I tried to do this operation for my minikube:

```
~ kubectl delete pod --all -n kube-system
pod "coredns-f9fd979d6-5n4b6" deleted
pod "etcd-minikube" deleted
pod "kube-apiserver-minikube" deleted
pod "kube-controller-manager-minikube" deleted
pod "kube-proxy-879lg" deleted
pod "kube-scheduler-minikube" deleted
```

It's okay. Pods deleted as wish. But if I do `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` I will see:

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-f9fd979d6-5d25r            1/1     Running   0          50s
etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          50s
kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          50s
kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          50s
kube-proxy-nlw69                   1/1     Running   0          43s
kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          49s
```

Okay. I thought it's ReplicaSet or DaemonSet:

```
➜  ~ kubectl get ds -n kube-system
NAME         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-proxy   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   18m
➜  ~ kubectl get rs -n kube-system
NAME                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
coredns-f9fd979d6   1         1         1       18m
```

It is true for `coredns` and `kube-proxy`. But what about others (`apiserver`, `etcd`, `controller` and `scheduler`)? Why are they still alive?

Comment: You need those pods to be alive to run kubernetes. Leave the pods in kube-system alone.

Comment: @Daniel Lee It is really interesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The control plane pods are run as [static Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/) - static Pods are not managed by the control plane controllers like e.g. DaemonSet and ReplicaSet. *Static pods* are instead managed by the Kubelet daemon on the local node directly.